# canvas c.getContext("2d") error

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using a  canvas in our landing page if i will include

```
var c = document.getElementById('canv'), 
    $ = c.getContext("2d");
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth, 
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight;
```

than other custom script not working 
like [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMM2PHIISKLN)

if i will remove `$ = c.getContext("2d");` this function than all custom js working fine.

> Do you have any idea how to fix this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have canvas tag with id as canv . I am quite sure that's missing in your application

Add

```
 <canvas id='canv'></canvas>
```

Its working fine you have problem in adding gradient , everything is 225 which is white , so it actually exist but you cant see .

```
  this.g.addColorStop(0, 'hsla(255,0%,0%,1)');
```

[Link](http://jsbin.com/xogusuzoji/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: thanks for replying. But  I have already mention, if you have check my demo link?

Comment: you can click on link and see below there write <script>  and  <canvas id='canv'></canvas> also: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMM1POM77M6J

Comment: It actually exist but your gradient color is stopping it @lalitbhakuni

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$` with `ctx` in `$ = c.getContext("2d");`
i.e. `ctx = c.getContext("2d");`

Comment: thanks for replaying it's working, But my canvas not working  @hirakJS